# Logitech MX Keys brightness keys does not work

Tags: keyboard, brightness, logitech

I recently bought Logitech's MX Keys keyboard. The keyboard seems to be working fine with Linux (Ubuntu 20.04, i3wm) except the brightness keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) are not working. These keys work on Windows 10 (dual boot) though.

`xev` shows no output on pressing these keys. However, it shows output on pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> without <kbd>Fn</kbd>. All other alternate <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> functions (backlight, media keys, etc.) are working fine.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Right, my mx keyboard shows the same behavior. So I can reassure you _for the first time_ - your hardware reacts as expected. No keyboard codes are detected for these two keys in x11. Maybe the keyboard sends these codes only if as host MSWIN is detected.

Comment: @Quasímodo Nothing shows up when pressing brightness keys on `acpi_listen`. As expected, the other media keys' events are registered.

Comment: have just recorded the usb-stream of the unified receiver via wireshark. all keypressings **except** for these two keys create a 'URB INTERRUPT'. For me this is a sign that the keyboard codes are not transmitted by the keyboard in this case.

Comment: @ingank thank you so much. Then I think a firmware upgrade from Logitech is only solution, right?

Comment: @mrpandey unfortunately no. on my keyboard is the latest firmware installed and shows the same behavior as yours.

Comment: just for the sake of completeness: as I thought before, both keys generate an `URB INTERRUPT - EVENT` (recorded with wireshark) under Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newest versions of [Solaar](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar) (I tested on 1.0.5) have pre-defined rules for these keys.
Also [logiops](https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops) works fine with mx keys with the following config:

```json
{
  name: "MX Keys Wireless Keyboard";

  buttons: ({
    cid: 0x00c7;
    action = {
      type: "Keypress";
      keys: ["KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN"];
    };
  }, {
    cid: 0x00c8;
    action = {
      type: "Keypress";
      keys: ["KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP"];
    };
  });
},
```

Comment: I have tried solaar earlier, but it didn't work. Maybe it was not the latest version. But logiops surely works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

MX Keys keyboard as well and my brightness keys have not worked either. This thread solved my issue.

I had to do the following exactly:

1. Install logiops with this command:

   ```
    $ sudo apt install logiops
   ```

   source: https://github.com/PixlOne/logiops

   launchpad site: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/logiops
2. Create /etc/logid.cfg if it does not exist with the following content as suggested above with the following additions:

line 1  -->>   devices: (

line 19 -->>   );

The following is my entire /etc/logid.cfg with only one device.

```json
devices: (
{
  name: "MX Keys Wireless Keyboard";

  buttons: ({
    cid: 0x00c7;
    action = {
      type: "Keypress";
      keys: ["KEY_BRIGHTNESSDOWN"];
    };
  }, {
    cid: 0x00c8;
    action = {
      type: "Keypress";
      keys: ["KEY_BRIGHTNESSUP"];
    };
  });
},
);
```

3. start and enable logiops with systemctl command below:

   ```
    $ sudo systemctl enable --now logid
   ```

Enjoy your brightness keys! I am.

Thanks to everyone here that lead me in the right direction.

cannabisindica

NOTE: I only have one Logitech device (MX Keys) so this above is my entire config. You may have more logitech devices so your config may have additions for those devices if needed. If that is the case please add this section to your current config.

Comment: Hello. A complete answer would say where to get this logiops app from and how to install and start it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip https://askubuntu.com/users/1134215/david - edited post per suggestions from David.

Answer (score 0):

Brightness keys on my Dell XPS-13 didn't work when I installed Lubuntu 20.04, either. I found a "brightness" app under "preferences" and that does control the screen brightness and contrast.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to spend much time downloading logiops and figuring out how to edit the .cfg file (which didn't even work for me in the end):

On my system, Solaar defaulted to Windows OS. Simply changing the OS to iOS or macOS made the brightness keys work for me. There are built in rules for the brightness keys but they don't seem to work when in Windows OS. Just go into the Solaar gui, locate the "Set OS" setting, click the lock twice to unlock, change the OS and click the lock to lock it back up and voila.